# Php type hinting to object properties existance

Tags: php, type-hinting

How can I hint, that argument I receive must to have several public properties?
Something like:

```
interface IPerson {
    public $surname;
    public $name;
}
class A {
    public function foo(IPerson $p) {
        return $p->surname . ' ' . $p->name;
    }
}
```

But since interfaces can't point to variables (why?), is behavior above even possible in PHP?
May be there is anything in some new php releases(`5.5-7.0`)?

I think main issue is `php` type system, where no `has property` concept?

Comment: 'I don't think there is a way in current PHP 5.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define getters in the interface:

```
interface IPerson {
    public function getSurname();
    public function getName();
}
class A {
    public function foo(IPerson $p) {
        return $p->getSurname() . ' ' . $p->getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: But I'll need to wrap a huge amount of foreign classes to implement this, simpler check `isset`'s without hinting...

Comment: This is how it's intended to be. By defining a getter for a property in the interface, the implementing class must return something (i.e. the property must exist).